# How to use local domain name instead local ip address in Mac?

Tags: localhost, ip-address, domain-name

I want to access to my local web-server in mac with domain name instead ip address at other devices.

For example, 'custom.domain:8080' instead '192.168.xx.xx:8080'

What is the most simple way to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/hosts`, and add the following line:

```
192.168.xx.xx custom.domain
```

Then visit http://custom.domain:8080

Answer (score 0):

Specific example:
settings > WiFi > Details

Edit the file `/etc/hosts`, and add the following line:

`192.168.0.105 mydomain.com`

[image]